# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 EF7 CODE FIRST is not connecting to SQL database from IIS. Works locally fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc

With poor documentation from Microsoft (site says still working...forever), I completed a web application with ASP.NET 4.5.2, MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5), EF7 -Code First, Angular JS in Visial Studio 2015. This is working fine locally including user registration- that is it is inserting data to SQL database.

However, when I published to File System & ran through IIS, database is not getting created automatically nor data got inserted(if database already existed)- The error just says
'An error occurred while processing your request.'
when trying to login or while registering user.

I did not have 'Databases' section in publish web option of Visual Studio 2015.

I just need this connectivity to database. Please help to resolve as this issue is sure to be faced by everyone.

Comment: Do you have a correct connection string for your production server? Does the database user in production have permission to create the database?

Comment: The automatic migrations of code first are a nicety for development, allowing you to focus on your application and not worry about the database-side of things. However, going into production is an entirely different beast and you *do* need to concern yourself with the database-side of things.

Comment: Yes, connection string is correct in web.config